magento 2.4.4 csp secure renderTag not working with generated content
I have a controller that inject a phtml via the
$this->_view->getLayout()->getBlock('block_name')->toHtml();
code. The problem is that the template for this block has an inline javascript. I have tried to use the secure renderTag() method but it doesn't work: when I inspect the page on the browser, instead of having the tag <script nonce>, I have the normal tag <script> as the render tag wasn't there. Eg, this is the original phtml:
<?php 
// some php code
?>

<div class="myclass"> 
   <!-- some html content --> 
</div>

<script>
require(['jquery'],function($){
        $(document).ready(function() {
            console.log('some text goes here');
        });
    });
</script>


This is the fixed template (the php and html parts are the same, I simply put the script part inside the renderTag method):
<?php 
// some php code
?>

<div class="myclass"> 
   <!-- some html content --> 
</div>

<?php
/** @var \Magento\Framework\View\Helper\SecureHtmlRenderer $secureRenderer */
    
    $scriptString = <<<script
    require(['jquery'],function($){
        $(document).ready(function() {
            console.log('some text goes here');
        });
    });
    script;
?>
<?= /* @noEscape */ $secureRenderer->renderTag('script', [], $scriptString, false) ?>


The fixed version should show up in the browser inspector as:
<script  nonce>
require(['jquery'],function($){
        $(document).ready(function() {
            console.log('some text goes here');
        });
    });
</script>

Instead, it just shows as plainly:
<script>
require(['jquery'],function($){
        $(document).ready(function() {
            console.log('some text goes here');
        });
    });
</script>

and of course the browser is throwing a csp error message.
Is there a way to whitelist this kind of inline scripts?

To fix this issue simply convert below code
From
<?= /* @noEscape */ $secureRenderer->renderTag('script', [], $scriptString, false) ?>
To
<?= /* @noEscape */ $secureRenderer->renderTag('script', ['nonce' => ''], $scriptString, false) ?>
If this answer works as your expected, please mark it as accepted. That indicates your issue is solved and makes it easier for others with the same issue to find a verified answer. And that would be great if you click the upvote button for the answer in case you feel it is useful.
Happy Coding

Hello @Lou Nik, does this fixed your issue or you still need any help?
